Is there a standard way to make sense of integrals of functions over infinite dimensional vector spaces?
For example, you have a function $f: R^{\mathbb{N}} \to R$ given by $f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}\frac{x_i}{i^2}$.
I want to integrate this over "infinite dimensional" boxes in $R^{\mathbb{N}}$ like the set $\{(x_0, x_1, x_2 ...) \ | \ \forall i \in N |x_i| \leq 1 \} \subseteq R^{\mathbb{N}}$. (and possibly more complicated "shapes").
I know basic measure theory, but struggle how to figure out how to make this make sense. Is there some standard way this is usually done? I need to do this because agents utility functions are or this form and I need an inner product on them.
(Also, to be clear this function is not well defined for all of $R^{\mathbb{N}}$, depending on the class of functions we're considering, we'd need to restrict the space for the sum to converge, that is clear, but its not the thing I'm having difficulty with)
